# Nuxt open graph meta tags not working in netlify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, metadata, server-side-rendering, netlify

I have a portfolio site which was working fine up until march, Recently when I tried to post a new blog and checked the linkpreview of the new blog, I was getting meta tags of the data mentioned in the nuxt.config.js instead of individual pages/articles.

Here is my nuxt config file

```
export default {
  target:'static',
  head: {
    title: "Kamran Memon | Portfolio",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en",
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      {
        name: "viewport",
        content:
          "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0",
      },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.png" },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

and in individual pages/articles I have the meta info like this

```
head() {
    return {
      title: 'About | Kamran Memon | Portfolio',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content:
            "I am Kamran Memon, A Frontend Developer with primary experience in Vue.js, Vuetify, Nuxt.js and have worked in Fintech and Health Care Industries",
        },
        {
          hid: 'author',
          name: 'author',
          content: 'Kamran Memon'
        },
        {
          hid: "keywords",
          name: "keywords",
          content: "Kamran Memon"
        },
        //Open Graph
        { hid: "og-type", property: "og:type", content: "website" },
        {
          hid: "og-title",
          property: "og:title",
          content: "About | Kamran Memon | Portfolio",
        },
        {
          hid: "og-desc",
          property: "og:description",
          content:
            "I am Kamran Memon, A  Frontend Developer with primary experience in Vue.js, Vuetify, Nuxt.js and have worked in Fintech and Health Care Industries",
        },
        {
          hid: "og-image",
          property: "og:image",
          content: "https://codewithkamran.com/assets/card-image.png",
        },
        { hid: "og-url", property: "og:url", content: "https://codewithkamran.com" },
        { hid: "t-type", name: "twitter:card", content: "summary_large_image" },
      ];
    }
  },
```

Everything works fine in local dev environment once I deploy it on netlify and check in any open graph checker it shows data from nuxt config file instead of individual pages/blogs.

I have been using https://metatags.io/ and https://www.opengraph.xyz/ for checking meta tags here are the results

[image]

I have tried several settings in nuxt.config `ssr:true` and `ssr:false` `target:server` but nothing seems to be working. It feels something is wrong on the netlify side. Has it anything to do with pre-rendering which I guess has been recently added in netlify?

Comment: It seems a Netlify issue, not Nuxt related, specially if it was working correctly before. I would ask in their community forum.

Comment: also it can be cached on those platforms, i think is best if you inspect the dom yourself using the devtools

Comment: @toniMichelCaubet I have tried inspecting in DOM everything looks fine over there. I could see expected meta data

Comment: are you using SSR? because if you are and you see the meta tags then you are fine but if you are using the mode spa then the meta tags are probably being generated in the client side only (check the generated source code to make sure) more info https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode/

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet  I think the mode property is deprecated, Now they use ssr: true|false, I haven't added ssr prop, I guess it is true by default. what should be the ideal setting for nuxt site to deploy on netlify?

Comment: That depends on your needs. If there's dynamic content perhaps you should false in order to avoid deploying constantly, but if its more an static site: normally `ssr: true`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Thanks I have tried it no luck. I have asked in the netlify community no answers yet. Can you share any ideas how can I debug it?

Comment: yes open the site and then right click anywhere and "view source code" if you see your metas there(consider using CTRL+F to search them) you should be good to go. Example (for google): view-source:https://www.google.com/

Comment: Tried this, I could see meta tags but those which are included in the nuxt.config.js file and not individual pages meta tags. When I inspect it shows properly as per the pages. Dont know if this is a netlify issue or nuxt. been 4 days cant find anything for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Mistakenly wrapped `<nuxt>` with `<client-only>` in the layout file in the earlier commits, due to which I was facing the issue.